# Exporting a bunch of Google Calendar .ics files, to a folder on Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, scripting, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-apps

I have several calendars in my Google account, for which I would like to set up a periodical back-up.

Each calendar has a specific export URL for its .ics file, e.g. https://calendar.google.com/calendar/exporticalzip?cexp=insert_long_string_of_characters

I'd like to take each export link for each calendar, and have some sort of script that would export the files to a designated folder on my Google Drive (instead of to my local machine)

Is such a thing possible?

Thanks!

Jamie

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. see [how to write a good stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Show us the code you tried so far and where it fails after reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To get specific export URL, you can use the method ['Files:get'](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) to get file's metadata by ID. Under the [`downloadUrl`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource) it has the `exportLinks` including (key). Retrieve the appropriate download URL provided in the file's metadata then retrieve the actual file content or link using the download URL.

To download files, you make an authorized `HTTP GET` request to the file's resource URL and include the query parameter *alt=media*

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B9jNhSvVjoIVM3dKcGRKRmVIOVU?alt=media
Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHESVbXTUv5mHMo3RYfmS1YJonjzzdTOFZwvyOAUVhrs

private static InputStream downloadFile(Drive service, File file) {
if (file.getDownloadUrl() != null && file.getDownloadUrl().length() > 0) {
try {
HttpResponse resp =
service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl()))
.execute();
return resp.getContent();
} catch (IOException e) {
// An error occurred.
e.printStackTrace();
return null;
}
} else {
// The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
return null;
}
}
```

There are some Google Doc formats and supported export MIME, check this document: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents