# Exporting an entire Google Calendar (all of its events) TO A FILE via API

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I have eight calendars in Google Calendar each having a bunch of events. I would like to export each of these calendars (with all of their events) to their own file. I'll be using Python to write the script, and the script would run nightly from my crontab.

Does the GCal API actually have (a) method(s) for doing this type of export? How would I go about doing this?

Apologies for such a generalized question -- I'm having trouble even getting started with this problem:

I've looked through the Calendar API Reference and was unable to find any clear method for exporting a calendar to a file.

I searched StackOverflow for `[google-calendar-api] export` and read through the first nine pages of results and there was [only one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38457581/exporting-a-bunch-of-google-calendar-ics-files-to-a-folder-on-google-drive) resembling my problem. The answer is about three years old and doesn't adequately answer the question (or, I just don't understand the answer enough to make use of it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method to *export* calendars in the Calendar API. Also depending on what is your desired output format, the adequate answer may be different. Here are some options that come to my mind:

1. Using the Google Calendar API. First of all you would need to call [CalendarList.list()](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) to obtain all your calendars, and after that use the [Events.list()](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) call to obtain every event for each calendar.
2. Import your calendar as an ICAL file using the Secret Address. The idea is that you can obtain a link to a download file that includes all your calendar information, and you simply have to issue a GET request to it. Bear in mind, however, that this address has to be kept private, as anybody possessing it can access all of your calendar information. You can read more about this in the official documentation [here](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37648?hl=en).

Comment: Option 2 would be ideal. When I tried this option earlier to grab a calendar, the `ics` file didn't seem to have any recurrence info about events in that calendar that are recurring. I searched through the ICS file and referred to RFC2445, RFC5545, and iCalendar.org for the fields that carry that info---and they're nowhere to be found in the `ics` file. Will option 2 not work if I need info about recurring events?

Comment: Hey @NickolasPeterO'Malley, I have checked my own `ics` extraction of my private calendar and I have found the recurrence information in the `RRULE` tag. I suggest you: 1. Identify a recurring event in your calendar. 2. Open your ics file with a text editor. 3. Search for the title associated to your recurring event. The first `RRULE` tag above this title should contain information about the event's recurrence. Does this apply for you? Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: It does work actually. I just realized after reading your comment and checking that I downloaded a calendar that doesn't have recurring events. There are RRULE lines in my other calendars. Thank you! Option 2 works perfectly.